# Elegant way to get count of elements in each model in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, oop, laravel-5.1

In each menu item I need to display the number of items contained inside. For example:

```
Users (22)
Posts (57)
Categories (14)
Cities (92)
```

Tried to do something like this:

**App/View/Composers/AddCountOfModels.php:**

```
namespace App\View\Composers;

use Illuminate\View\View;
use App\User;
use App\Post;
use App\Category;
use App\City;

class AddCountOfModels
{
  public function compose(View $view)
  {
    $view->with('count_of', [
      'users' => User::count(),
      'posts' => Post::count(),
      'categories' => Category::count(),
      'cities' => City::count(),
    ]);
  }
}
```

**App/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php:**

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\View\Composers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
  public function boot()
  {
    $this->app['view']->composer('_layouts.backend', Composers\AddCountOfModels::class);
  }
}
...
```

**menu.blade.php:**

```
@extends('_layouts.backend')

@section('menu')
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
  <li class="header">Menu</li>
  <li class="menu-item">Users ({{ $count_of['users'] }})</li>
  <li class="menu-item">Posts ({{ $count_of['posts'] }})</li>
  <li class="menu-item">Categories ({{ $count_of['categories'] }})</li>
  <li class="menu-item">Cities ({{ $count_of['cities'] }})</li>
</ul>
@endsection
```

But it looks like a clumsy because models can be much more. 
Please help find a more beautiful solution.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want to do?

Comment: I need to pass to menu.blade.php the number of rows contained in each model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand you, but I'll give it a go

```
// in controller
// change with your models location
$model_files = \File::allFiles('../app/models'); 

foreach($model_files as $model_file)
{
    $pos = strrpos($model_file->getRelativePathname(), ".");
    // add your path
    $models[] = 'App\Models\\'.substr($model_file->getRelativePathname(), 0, $pos);
}   

return view('layouts.app')->with(compact('models'));

// in view      
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
    <li class="header">Menu</li>
    @foreach($models as $model)
        <li class="menu-item">{{ $model }} ({{ $model::count() }})</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```